# Can I add specific columns to all DataGrids without using code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I know I can do this in XAML to add a column to a specific DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I also know that I can do the same in code.

```
DataGridColumn dwa = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn ();
grid.Columns.Add (dwa);
```

But is it possible to do this using XAML and apply it to all DataGrids? I can apply styles using a ResourceDictionary but I don't know about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `Columns` property is readonly. So using a Style cannot set it (via Setter) as well as somehow add a `DataGridColumn` to it. That means you would be stuck that way. However there is a workaround, instead of using multi DataGrids in your window, you can just use multi Controls, then add some Style targeting Control type and set the `Template` to a `DataGrid`. Here is a simple example:

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="Control">
       <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate>
               <DataGrid>
                  <DataGrid.Columns>
                     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
                     <DataGridTextColumn Header="City"></DataGridTextColumn>
                  </DataGrid.Columns>
               </DataGrid>
           </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
     </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition/>
     <RowDefinition/>
     <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <!-- use 3 controls instead of 3 DataGrids -->
  <Control></Control>
  <Control Grid.Row="1"></Control>
  <Control Grid.Row="2"></Control>
</Grid>
```

My advice is try building some view model, then you just need to assign the `ItemsSource` (which can be set via a Style Setter), of course that way we have to use the default `AutoGenerateColumns` feature of the DataGrid.